# Get User ID Within Custom Controller

Tags: laravel-5

I've got a Laravel app set up with user authentication, and a form on the user's homepage after logging in. The form posts to a custom controller. What I need is to be able to retrieve the ID of the current user (the one logged in) from within the controller, so it can be saved to a model along with the formdata.

It seems extremely easy, but I'm struggling to get it working. I have:

```
use Auth;
```

at the top of my custom controller. Inside the function that the form posts to I have tried:

```
var_dump(Auth::id());
var_dump(Auth::user()->id);
var_dump(Auth::user());
```

All of these return null.

Comment: First test if user is logged in with `if (Auth::check())`

Comment: This : `Auth::user()->id` should be correct. Did you add  `use Auth; on top of your controller? In order to retrive the user id the user has to be logged in.

Comment: I see, the user had timed out and I didn't have the auth check to make sure they were still logged in.

Answer (score 0):

As per mokiSRB's suggestion, I added a check for:

```
if (Auth::check())
```

And found that the user had been timed out without my knowing. This check is thus important to wrap anywhere you need to retrieve information about the logged in user.